# How to quickly display a large (GB) text file?

Tags: delphi, text, delphi-xe, large-data

I want to quickly show the content of a large text file in my app without loading the whole file in memory.

**How others are doing it?**

1. [Total Commander](http://ghisler.com/) is an **wonderful tool** that has an amazing internal viewer that does it. It opens ANY files no matter how big, instantaneously (or that fast that I can't time it). I tried it on 12GB file. There is no significant memory usage (only ~100KB) when it shows the file. How they do it?
2. SynEdit - the program freezes (minutes) as it will first parse the entire file THEN it will show the text.
3. [LargeTextFile](http://sourceforge.net/projects/largetextfile)
   Approximates the size of the scroll bar. The scroll bar is adjusted continuously (it shrinks) until the program finally reads the entire file (could take minutes). Compared with Total Commander it really sucks.
4. UltraEdit 32 -  the program freezes (I had to kill it as I didn't had patience (or ram) to let is finish)

Comment: because they don't read lines. they read a limited amount of BYTES. e.g. if the display window can only display 200 characters, then you read the file 200 bytes at a time.

Comment: yes, but that doesn't mean they have to read an ENTIRE line at once. a file is still just a sequence of bytes, no matter how many/few lines are in it. if the 200 bytes they read don't contain a line break, then they can strip off X chars at the start, read X more chars and tack those onto the end of the "in memory" data. effectively "scrolling" the line.

Comment: Use `CreateFileMapping` and `MapViewOfFile` to access the raw bytes of the file quickly, and then you can "slide" the view around during scrolling, and parse lines within each views data as needed.

Comment: read 200 bytes, display text, then scan forward/count chars until you do read a linebreak. update scrollbar once "distance" is known.

Comment: @MarcB - Ok. Hands-down example: 3GB text file with lines of any size between 0 to 12000 chars. Can you tell me the size of the scroll bar?  :)   (I am just trying to explain my problem).

Comment: like I said. read enough to display, thens can the file in its entirety to calculate how far things should scroll. and frankly, once your scroll indicator hits 1 pixel high, it's useless to get more accurate - invisible scroll pointers are useless. I suggest you try that app with a SLOW storage system.  e.g. something that can make the file be read at a few k/sec, and you'll see that the scrollbar indicator will start full-size, then gradually shrink down as the file's scanned for line counts.

Comment: @Silvester Which one is it: *How to display a large (GB) text file using less than 100KB RAM?* or *How to calculate the size of a scroll-bar based on xyz.*?

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/projects/dzlargetextview/ is my implementation. It generates a line index in the background and writes it as a file, so it only needs to be generated once. While it is generating the index, you can already start viewing. I tested it with a full dump of Wikipedia as xml file.

Comment: @dummzeuch - actually I just looked over your dzlargetextview JUST before posting. But generating an index file for a 12GB file is rather... slow. Simply reading the files once to count the lines will solve the problem muuuch faster and without any writing. But I want to do it even faster (instantaneously) as Total Commander does it. Anyway, thanks. I learned stuff from your web site. Great resource!

Comment: @Silvester I have no idea what you are talking about. You should consider the Remy's approach above.

Comment: @RawN - Related to your "Which one is it" - I don't have two questions. I have a single question with a self-proposed, possible answer. If you know any of the answers just post it and I PROMISE will accept your answer :)

Comment: Not a duplicate as in "Calculate scrollbar height according to amount of hidden contents" the answer (amount of hidden content) is already known.

Comment: Believe that viewer, that opens huge file fast, does not read all lines and does not count them. It just shows approximate scroll bar position based on byte position.

Comment: There is no problem to read the last line in any size file. Just read some kilobytes from the end of file. Note that reading of full 3GB file contents takes about 1-1.5 minutes for traditional HDDs.

Comment: @MBo Can you please post the formula (as comment or answer) used to calculate the scroll bar size? We know the file size and number of lines that could fit on screen. BUT the no of characters is variable as this depends on font and line length. Obviously Total Cmd is not reading the whole file. I don't contradict you here! They must be using a very accurate formula to instantaneously calculate scroll bar size.

Comment: I deleted formula for thumb size - it is always small. Scroll bar full size (max value) for large files might be chosen as arbitrary like 1000000.

Comment: Again - there is no need to count from the start to set at the end - just read some ending piece.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126924/discussion-between-silvester-and-mbo).

Comment: @Silvester Viewer of Total Commander is great for just __viewing__ files of any type. Text editor UltraEdit can be used also for viewing large and huge files. But UltraEdit is preconfigured for editing efficiently small text files as being a text __editor__. Some configuration settings must be changed for using UltraEdit on large/huge files, see UltraEdit power tip [Large file text editor](http://www.ultraedit.com/support/tutorials_power_tips/ultraedit/large_file_handling.html). Then UltraEdit reads, displays and edits a huge file also in blocks like Total Commander.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just read the file in blocks (e.g. by chunks of 64KB or 128KB), then you compute lines within those blocks. Don't try to work with lines for the whole document (as Silvester proposes), but with blocks and offsets, then trick the UI to emulate the fact that you don't know the lines.

The scrollbar won't follow the lines, but the offset in file, then within the blocks. If you move the bar, you will guess the closest line begin and end in the chunk.

The drawback of it is that it is easier to have a maximum line length, which is the chunk. TotalCommander will wrap very long lines, I suppose due to its internal chunking algorithm.

Answer (score 3):

Written in Delphi, source code available:

> This is a very simple tool for displaying large text files where large
>   means they don't fit into the 2 GB memory which a 32 bit Windows process
>   can use. I successfully tested it displaying a 48 GB XML dump of the
>   English language Wikipedia which contained 789.577.286 lines of text.

https://sourceforge.net/projects/dzlargetextview/

(Yes, I know, this is an old question, but an example might still be helpful.)

Comment: Thanks. Never too late. The lib Seems impressive.

Comment: The website only lists an EXE file. No source code there.

Comment: The source code is in svn, The required libraries are defined as svn:external, so checking out the trunk should result in everything necessary to compile. https://sourceforge.net/p/dzlargetextview/code/HEAD/tree/

Comment: I didn't had the time to look into the code. I just tried the demo EXE provided. One question. Why is the program indexing? What I try to achieve is something like Total Commander's Internal File Viewer (F3). It will open ANY file no matter how big instantly. No disk activity, no indexing. So, is it possible to (easily) get rid of indexing in dzlargetextview?

Comment: The indexing is necessary to break the file into lines.